# IntelliJ IDEA Git Clone - How to remove Public Key Authentication

Tags: git, intellij-idea

While configuring Git Clone, I accidentally selected "Public Key Authentication".

Now, the popup doesnot appear and
I donot know, how to change this setup from "Public Key Authentication" to other option.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have use an SSH URL when cloning your repository (ie, not an HTTPS one, starting with https://)
A possible reason no popup is shown is, for an HTTPS URL, a git credential helper might have already cached your remote hosting service credentials.

For SSH URL (`git@xxx:<me>/myproject`), try and clone it again in a different folder, to see if can, in that second clone, *not* select "Public Key Authentication".
This assumes you are using a passphrase-protected private key of course.

- If the private key was *not* passphrase protected, no popup would be needed.
- If the private key was passphrase-protected, and already added to an `ssh-agent`, again, no popup would be needed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What change should be done in IntelliJ so that I could get the popup again ? Because, I couldnot disable the "Public Key Authentication" and switch to other option.

Comment: @Reeshav Can you edit your question with a screenshot illustrating what you see when doing a new clone?

Comment: When I try for new Clone, it directly attempts for "Public Key Authentication". 
Looks like, the pop-up value is cached somewhere in IntelliJ. 
As the popup doesnot appear, I'm not able to deselect the "Public Key Authentication".

Comment: @Reeshav For testing, can you try that same new clone after a reboot?

Comment: @ VonC Actually I have tried system restart as well as Invalidate Caches already. Any idea, where the popup values gets stored ?

Comment: @Reeshav No immediate idea. A screenshot would still be helpful.

Comment: In IntelliJ, followed these steps 
(1) VCS > Git > Clone  
(2) In the popup shown, entered the URL (copied from GitHub) and 
Directory (Local System Path). 
(3) Clicked on "Clone". It didnot show the popup, but used the existing setup of "Public Key Authentication" and the clone failed.
Need to find out a way to get the popup so that "Public Key Authentication" can be changed ...

Comment: @Reeshav Is the URL copied from GitHub an HTTPS one or an SSH one?

Comment: It's a SSH URL. It starts with "git@github.company.com...."
Basically the problem is that I should uncheck the box - "Public Key Authentication".
For this, the pop-up should be displayed when I press the "clone" button and it's not happening right now.

Comment: @Reeshav For testing, can you try and clone it with HTTPS URL, then clone it again with SSH, just in case, the switch of URL protocol somehow reset the SSH clone policy?

Comment: @ VonC
Tried the clone with HTTPS. After which did the SSH Clone again.
But getting error message 
Clone failed. Sign and send pubkey. signing failed. agent refused operation 
// Permission denied (publickey) // Could not read from remote repository

Comment: @Reeshav What OS and git version are you using?

Comment: Working with Linux (RedHat) and git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: 1.8.3.1??? Is is an RHEL 6 or 7.7? Any possibility to upgrade Git there?

Comment: @ VonC
RHEL Version 7.8
Do you think that Git needs an upgrade ? If yes, which version of Git preferred ?

Comment: @Reeshav Not sure if there is one ready for RHEL. I known I am on RHEL 7.8 and... I compile my own Git (2.29.2)

Comment: Tried the command
...sudo yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable install git
...But, getting the message
...Package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: @Reeshav Exactly, on this stable version, 1.8 is as good as it get (which is why I recompile Git myself)

Comment: Ok... Sounds good. Any suggestion on this error message ---
Clone failed. Sign and send pubkey. signing failed. agent refused operation // Permission denied (publickey) // Could not read from remote repository